# Ubuntu 20.04: How to disable Alt+g needed by Emacs goto line feature?

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys

I need to press `Meta-g g` to jump to a particular line in the Emacs editor.

However, the `Right Meta/Alt g` opens the desktop's **"Type your Command"** prompt. *(I need to press the right-side Meta because of touch-typing.)*

I can't find the above key binding anywhere under `System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts`.

**EDIT**

[image]

This is the Unity desktop on Ubuntu 20.04, upgraded from 18.04, after I press Right Meta-g (or Right Alt-g) **with keyboard focus on Emacs**.

If the keyboard focus is on Chrome browser when pressing Right Alt-g, then Chrome's menu appears (instead of "Type your command").

If the focus is on the Desktop (after left-clicking in a blank area of the Desktop), then just like you say, nothing happens.

Apparently, the combo of Emacs and Desktop isn't playing well.

Comment: This may help. https://www.howtogeek.com/127162/how-to-create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-browser-actions-and-extensions-in-google-chrome/

Comment: That link is about Chrome. I need to disable the global shortcut used by Unity desktop

Comment: Your question says used by the Desktop but by my Chrome browser

Comment: It says, *not* used by the Desktop...

Comment: What is the desktop you use? I cannot reproduce Right Alt g opening a run dialog, and in the standard desktop, that dialog is entitled: "Run a Command". Use "edit" to add that information to your question.

Comment: @vanadium Added an **EDIT** section with a screenshot and some clarifications.